# Show Toast in googleMap Activity

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I´m doing an app that has a googlemaps activity which shows you a map with your location provided by the gps.
I have a method that detects the distance between you and a point that is updated every location changed, I wan´t to show something, a toast for example when you are near the location. But Toast doesn´t work in this activity.

Comment: What do you mean with "Toast doesn't work". What happens, if you try to show a toast? A toast may however easily be missed by the user. So why don't you show a location marker at the users location with a corresponding information window?

Comment: With Toast doesn´t work I mean is not shown, I have made a test writting the toast on the on map ready but toast is not shown. I don´t need a location market I need something like a toast

Comment: Maybe you should add your relevant part of coding. I just tried it, in the onMapReady-Callback, and the toast was shown. It's important to have the context from the activity (it's no parameter of onMapReady) and of course to call the show-method of the toast.

Comment: I´m going to try again in onmapready again thanks